# How do I get an image's handle in vb.net

Tags: c, vb.net, image, handle

I'm interfacing with a library written in C which requires I pass images as Int32 handles. How do I represent an image file in VB as an integer? Or, more specifically, how do I get a resource's handle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Bitmap.GetHbitmap()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx) function to get a `HBITMAP` for your image (assuming you're using bitmaps). You'll have to make sure you properly clean up this value once you're done with it using [`DeleteObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For example (this is really from MSDN):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

...

using ( Bitmap bm = new Bitmap ( 10, 10 ) )
{
    IntPtr hBitmap = bm.GetHbitmap ();

    // Do something with hBitmap.

    DeleteObject ( hBitmap );
}
```

On the API level different types of images are represented with different handles, so if you're using an icon, you'll have to use the [`Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.handle.aspx) property of the icon instead. This handle doesn't need to be freed because it's not a copy.